# React native should I pass props or use Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux

So I have a router component which sits at the top of the screen in my app.  There is a menu button in this component which is visible when certain other pages/components are loaded.

When this menu button is clicked, I need to communicate this to the component which is currently displaying the page so that it can display a context menu.

The context menu and the menu button both work independently.  However, I'm confused at how to wire it up.  How do I efficiently communicate a true/false toggle between those two components?  I thought I could do it with props but then I feel that you cannot update the props after they've been passed.  This leads me to think I may need to have a store implemented which both components can read/write from/to.  This way the router component will update the store on each menu button click, and the other component could have its state updated based on the store's state which I could use to toggle the menu visible/hidden.

Does that make sense and if so what's the best way of tackling it?

*Router code:* - Parent, `menu()` fires when clicking the Menu button

```
const RouterRecipeComponent = () => {
  function menu() {
    console.log('clicky');
  }

  const MenuIcon =
  (<TouchableOpacity
    onPress={() => menu()}
    style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', width: 30, height: 30 }}
  >
    <Text>MENU</Text>
  </TouchableOpacity>);


  return (
    <Router
      sceneStyle={styles.sceneStyleWithSettings}
      navigationBarStyle={styles.navBar}
      titleStyle={styles.navBarTitle}
      barButtonIconStyle={styles.barButtonIconStyle}
    >
      <Scene
        key="Recipes"
        component={Recipes}
        title={content.recipe_heading}
        rightTitle="Menu" initial
        renderRightButton={() => MenuIcon}
      />
```

*Recipes code* - Displays a bunch of stuff including the settings panel (code included) which will be toggled visible/hidden on each click of the menu button in the above Router code.  So my thoughts are to be able to toggle the state `settingsPanel` true/false to display the below:

```
renderSettingsPanel() {
    LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
    if (this.state.settingsPanel === true) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.settingsPanel}>
          {this.theSettings()}
        </View>
      );
    }
    return (
      <View style={[styles.settingsPanel, { top: -80, position: 'absolute', opacity: 10 }]}>
        {this.theSettings()}
      </View>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Could you post your code? Yes you shouldn't change props but if it's a router, it's the one creating the component so at that point you can set the props. In general it's indeed better to use something like Redux though. But anyway without seeing the code it's hard to tell.

Comment: Code added, thank you

Comment: where is your redux/store code. What you have in mind is correct. That way you can share the state as application state.

Comment: I don't have any redux implemented yet - my question was whether or not I would need a flux system for this application or if I could do it with a simpler method.